# Returning json from the kdb webserver

Tags: kdb

From the qprompt for e.g. we can run,

```
x: select from table
.j.j x
```

How do I return the table results of http url get requests (e.g. `host:port/?select from table`) made to the kdb webserver in json as opposed to plain text?

I can get the table result in text and parse the html response, but would prefer to get the results from the http server itself in json

Thanks

Comment: "http://localhost:5555/?.j.j select from tab" doesn't work?

Comment: One of the first things I tried but doesnt work for me. Is it supposed to? Im also on an older version of kdb prior to 3.2, so I've manually loaded json.k

Comment: if `.j.j select from table` works from the q console then it should work via http as well. What happens when you open `localhost:5555/?.j.j select from tab` in a browser?

Comment: it works for me on 3.4 anyway. Pretty sure it would work for >=3.2 also

Comment: sorry for the late response. I'd made a mistake and the suggestion above ended up working for me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To Get Data as JSON object you have to set Content-Type:application/json in response header in KDB response

For That you have to provide .z.ph function custom implementation and append below line to stating of your response data.

```
  "HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\nContent- Type:application/json\r\n\r\n"
```

Sample implementation

```
 .z.ph:{:"HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\nContent- Type:application/json\r\n\r\n", .j.j table_data }
```

In z.ph function you will get a dictionary as input

```
x[0]: query from browser
x[1]: request header
```

Now you have to write custom implementation to process your x[0] query

```
 If query through Http client was http://localhost:2001/?select from t then
 x[0] will be "?select%20from%20t" where t is kdb table 
 you have to decode x[0] string to remove white space and other character in string.
    value (decoded string);
```